# BInary search tree transversals

Tags: python, unit-testing, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am confused on the recursion in binary search tree transversals, I'm just lost since i need to return a list at the end and don't get how to save the values.It adds values like this shown below and I don't get what data stype is used to save the values like that also I don't think I'm moving through the tree correctly here is my code for , not sure if my unittest is correct either

```
def inorder(self):

    print("IN INORDER_______________________________")
    print("Printing self.value" + str(self.__value))
    result = []

    if self.__left:
        print("theres self.left")
        print(self.__value)
        #result = result + self.__left 
        #print(result)
        return self.__left.inorder()
        result 
        print(result + "RESULTS")

    if self.__right:

        print("theres self.right")
        print(self.__value)
        return self.__right.inorder()  

    return result



def test_inorder(self):
    bt = family_tree()
    bt.add(15, "jim")
    bt.add(20, "jamie")
    bt.add(25, "fred")
    bt.add(35, "howard")
    bt.add(30, "kc")
    x = bt.inorder()

    expected = '''(15, 'jim'),(20, 'jamie'),(25, 'fred'),(30, 'howard'),(35, 'kc')'''
    self.assertEquals(str(x), expected)
    t = family_tree(bt)
    self.assertEquals(str(t), expected)
```

Comment: I guess there some mistake in your `inorder` method. The code located after the return statement (for example in a branch like your `if self.__right`) is never executed. Excluding the print statement your function could be reduced to something like ```def inorder(self):
        if self.__left: return self.__left.inorder()
        elif self.__right: return self.__right.inorder()
        else: return []
``` Not a precise answer but you can use an other attribute (let's say`self.result`) of your object to add the value you need to store on each recursion until you're done and return it.

Answer (score 4):

There is a problem in your inorder implementation ; you return the values instead of connect them together.

Here is my implementation based on your code:

```
def inorder(self):
    result = []
    if self.__left:
        result += self.__left.inorder()

    result.append(self.__value)

    if self.__right:
        result += self.__right.inorder()

    return result
```